# Run gradle bootBuildImage Error:Can't find bundle for base name jakarta.servlet.LocalStrings, locale en_US

Tags: java, spring-boot

I cant run gradle bootBuildImage in rocty linux 9.1 with a Springboot project.

```
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name jakarta.servlet.LocalStrings, locale en_US
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2045) \~\[com.unimet.test.graalvm.GraalvmApplication:na\]
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1683) \~\[com.unimet.test.graalvm.GraalvmApplication:na\]
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1586) \~\[com.unimet.test.graalvm.GraalvmApplication:na\]
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1549) \~\[com.unimet.test.graalvm.GraalvmApplication:na\]
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:858) \~\[com.unimet.test.graalvm.GraalvmApplication:na\]
        at jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.\<clinit\>(GenericServlet.java:51) \~\[com.unimet.test.graalvm.GraalvmApplication:6.0.0\]
        ... 75 common frames omitted
```

```
system:rocty linux 9.1
build:gradle 7.6
run:gradle bootBuildImage
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native' version '0.9.18'
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to missing metadata for the Jakarta Servlet API; the native image is trying to load a resource bundle that was not included in the native image at build time.

I've submitted [a PR to fix that in the GraalVM metadata repository](https://github.com/oracle/graalvm-reachability-metadata/pull/213).

In the meantime, you can add the following content to a new file `src/main/resources/META-INF/native-image/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api/resource-config.json` in your project:

```json
{
  "bundles": [
    {
      "name": "jakarta.servlet.LocalStrings",
      "locales": [
        "und"
      ],
      "condition": {
        "typeReachable": "jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "jakarta.servlet.http.LocalStrings",
      "locales": [
        "und"
      ],
      "condition": {
        "typeReachable": "jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```